# Change Created Date in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I manage a request list in SharePoint 2013, and I need to import some requests from another list.  However, I want to keep the original request date rather than have SharePoint assign the current date/time that I upload the requests, so I want to change the default "Created" date field.  I got this to work for a date column that I added:

```
var duedate = new Date(2015,01,11).toISOString();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    ID: 5,
    valuepairs: [["DueDate", duedate]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    }
});
```

It doesn't work for the "Created" field though - I think because it's read only.  I need a way to make the "Created" field editable so I can change the date.  I have a lot of code already written that references this column so I would rather not make a new column that defaults to "Created" unless changed.

Bonus: my next task will be to change the default "Author" field so hopefully the solution can also make that field editable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: you cant. System fields such as `Created`, `Modified`, `Created By`, `Modified By` are not supported to be updated via SharePoint Web Services `UpdateListItems` operation.

> Note: `Created By (Author)` and `Modified By(Editor)` fields can be
>   updated in this manner only for **non-library** SharePoint lists

But there is a workaround. Basically the reason why those field could not be updated is because they are declared as **ReadOnly**. So, after modifying list schema to make system fields available for modification (set `ReadOnly` attribute to false) as shown below for `Created` field:

```
var updateSystemFields = "<Fields>" + 
   "<Method ID='1'>" + 
      "<Field ID='{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}' ColName='tp_Created' RowOrdinal='0' ReadOnly='FALSE' Type='DateTime' Name='Created' DisplayName='Created' StorageTZ='TRUE' SourceID='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3' StaticName='Created' FromBaseType='TRUE' Version='4' ShowInNewForm='FALSE' ShowInEditForm='FALSE' />" +
   "</Method>"  +
"</Fields>";
$().SPServices({
  operation: "UpdateList",
  listName: "Requests",
  listProperties:"",
  updateFields: updateSystemFields,
  newFields: "",
  deleteFields: "",
  listVersion: "",
  async: false,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status){ 
      console.log('List schema has been modified'); 
  }
});
```

list item `Created` field value could be updated using `UpdateListItems` operation:

```
var dueDateVal = new Date('2016-01-01 6:00:00').toISOString();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    ID: 1,
    valuepairs: [["Created", dueDateVal]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         console.log('List item has been updated');
    }
});
```

Comment: It works!  Thanks again @Vadim!  How did you know the stuff to put in the field tag though?  Where can I find it for author?  Especially field ID and version.

Comment: @SeeingSpots, i find RPC protocol pretty convinient to investigate SharePoint artifacts (lists, fields and etc.) via browser. You could take a look at [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/88848/10610) for a more details